# Why does <ol> not inherit <html> font-size?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, font-size

In my CSS file, I have:

```
html {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

However, in my page, there's an `<ol>` element whose resulting font size is clearly smaller.

Why doesn't `<ol>` inherit `<html>`'s `font-size`?

Comment: Please create a fiddle. `ol` nor `p` has the same default font-size: 100%.

Comment: As some others have pointed out, it probably has to do with default styles. I recommend you to read more about css resets http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
html{
    font-size:1.3em;
}
ol{
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/enomqof6/
or go for a [reset.css](http://cssreset.com/) file, which overrides default browser stylesheets.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the universal selector? Like this:

```
* {font-size: 1.3em;}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like :

```
html {font-size:1.3em !important} ;
```

As a second way you can give the style by javascript

Comment: Sorry, don't provide answer to question.

Comment: That will stop more specific, but unimportant, rules from being applied to the `html` element. It won't do a thing for other elements that either inherit the font size or have theirs set relative to their parent element's.